# Improve reusability of native code

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm trying to make some JNI code more portable from one app to another.
The ultimate goal is to make a native code library which can be used in any app.

What I have done so far:

Created a Java class whose sole purpose is to call native method:

```
package my.example.nativelib;
public class JavaToC {
    public static void loadLib() {
        System.loadLibrary("myLib");
    }

    public static int fooNative(int[] datas) {

        return foo(datas);
    }
    public native static int foo(int[] datas);
 }
```

Implemented JNI_OnLoad on the C++ side to use javaToC

```
static const char*  JavaWrapper = "my/example/nativelib/JavaToC";
jint foo(JNIEnv* env, jobject javaThis, jintArray datas)
{
    return 0;
}

jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* pVm, void* reserved) 
{
    JNIEnv* env;
    if (pVm->GetEnv(reinterpret_cast<void**>(&env), JNI_VERSION_1_6) != JNI_OK) {
       return -1;
    }

    JNINativeMethod nm[1];
    nm[0].name = "foo";
    nm[0].signature = "([I)I";
    nm[0].fnPtr = (void*)foo;

    jclass cls = env->FindClass(JavaWrapper);
    env->RegisterNatives(cls, nm, 1);

    return JNI_VERSION_1_6;
}

void JNI_OnUnload(JavaVM* pVm, void* reserved)
{
    JNIEnv* env;
    if (pVm->GetEnv(reinterpret_cast<void**>(&env), JNI_VERSION_1_6) != JNI_OK) {
        return;
    }

    jclass cls = env->FindClass(JavaWrapper);
    env->UnregisterNatives(cls);

    return;
}
```

So with that I can, anywhere in my app, call `JavaToC.foo()`. More convenient than the method which forces you to link a specific native call to a specific class.
But if someone else wants to use my native code, they still have to create a specific package with the class JavaToC.

**Is there a another way to improve the reusability of JNI native code?**

Do you know some native libs that I can use for reference?

Comment: Particularly for Android Studio/Gradle for Android, package the native code and the JNI wrapper Java class in an Android library project published as an AAR. [My CWAC-AndDown library](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-anddown) is published this way.

Comment: Working with eclipse for now, but i keep the AAR tip in mind when will switch to A.S and Gradle. So a JNI wrapper Java class is the way to go  if i want to distribute some jni code ?

Comment: That's certainly how I would distribute it.

Comment: Note that Android imposes no restrictions on the name of the package/class, and it does not have to be related to the APK package name.

Comment: FYI, using a tool like [JavaCPP](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp) would probably help quite a bit with usability.

Answer (score 0):

The best method I have come up with is a *portable* stand alone library that is then linked with JNI wrapper code.  Take a look at [JNativeHook](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook) and its backing library [libUIOHook](https://github.com/kwhat/libuiohook).  JNativeHook implements a [JNI layer](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook/tree/master/src/jni) that is a simple abstraction of the [libUIOHook](https://github.com/kwhat/libuiohook/blob/master/include/uiohook.h#L387) API.  The backing library can then be dynamically or statically linked to the JNI wrapper library or used in any standalone non-java application.  That should give you very good reuse with the added bonus of not having to debug your native code though the JVM.

I am not sure the RegisterNatives approach is really going to give you anything as far as code reuse is concerned... but it will make your code a lot more complicated.  Even if you change your native method names, they still need to accept all of your JNI arguments so you will end up doing something like dynamically loading a native shared library and then trying to map the exported functions to something you can use on the fly in Java... which is starting to sound a lot like [JNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access).

Comment: Alex, there are <s>two</s> three advantages to `RegisterNatives` approach. _First_, it helps when the number of native methods is few dozen (and probably they are spread over a dozen of classes). You simply don't want to have an **.so** with so many exported functions. _Second_, when you want to control discoverability of the methods. Simple `nm -D` will not be a useful tool for reverse engineering your library. _Third_, it **is possible** to dynamically decide which class to connect (`JNI_OnLoad()` can discover the environment in which it was invoked). But usually, it is not worth the effort.